# Firebase Admin with Database in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am using Firebase's Admin SDK. It also offers to use the [Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) as admin.

The type definition for the created Firebase Admin App looks as follows:

```
import * as firebaseAdmin from 'firebase-admin';

export type FirebaseContext = {
  firebaseAdmin: firebaseAdmin.app.App;
};
```

So far, it worked fine. However, if I am using Firebase's `TIMESTAMP` feature, it throws a type error:

```
firebaseAdmin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP

// Property 'ServerValue' does not exist on type '(url?: string | undefined) => Database'.ts(2339)
```

It should be said that the `firebaseAdmin` instance comes as argument from a function and is thus defined as `FirebaseContext.firebaseAdmin` from earlier.

So, did I do anything wrong with the earlier type definition? Because, if I don't pass the firebase instance via the function's arguments but import it directly from its module, it doesn't complain about the type definition. So there must be something wrong with the `type FirebaseContext`.

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you are now trying to get the `database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` object from a `FirebaseApp` instance. But the object is actually defined on the global `firebase`, and not on an app instance. So you will have to explicitly import `firebase`/`admin` and call `database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` on *that*, i.e. `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` or `admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Yes. That’s what I did in the end. I was just wondering if I could do something about the type to make it right for passing the Firebase instance as argument in functions.

Comment: It's not about type coercion, but about the actual object that you use. A `FirebaseApp` instance has a `database()` method, but not the `database` property that `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is defined on.

Comment: Now I get it. On the Firebase instance, the database is a function, on the imported object, it isn’t. Thanks! :)

Comment: Good to hear that it clicked Robin. I sometimes wonder if it was worth separating the (global) values from the app instance values. The approach we used saves memory, but you're definitely not the first one to fall into this trap. :-/